# How to write a while loop

Tags: java

So I'm writing some code for a card game and within this card game I have coded how the first round works. My question is how I would be able to repeat this code over and over again until the cards run out( since each card can only be used once). I'm thinking that I have to use a while loop. For convenience I will explain what each of the methods here do so that you may understand, so please bear with me. Some of this is useless code that I haven't gotten to complete yet and make useful.3

The rules to the game : https://tobakumokushirokukaiji.fandom.com/wiki/E_Card

** Here are the methods : **

**typeOfCard();** - this tells you which side you are playing on and is decided randomly, so far you can only play on the Emperor side.

**winOrLose()** - this is the last method i worked on before making this post, this is what I am trying to implement to allow me to replace the current win or loss output as strings which i can call easier than print statements. I want to make this so that the games which are won can set the int wincounter to 1 so it can print this out.

**emperorsTurn()** - this is the method that asks the main questions of which card you would like to play versus the computer.

**wincounter()** - some code i need to delete so dont worry about this

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CardGame {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numberOfCards = 7;
        if (numberOfCards > 6) {
            numberOfCards--;
            //System.out.println("your number of cards is " +numberOfCards);


        }
        typeOfCard();
    }


    public static void typeOfCard() {
        Random card  = new Random();
        int number = 0;


        for (int counter =1; counter <=3;counter++){
            number = 1+card.nextInt(2);    }

        if (number == 1)    {
            System.out.println("your are playing on the emperor side");

        }
        if (number ==2){
            System.out.println("You are playing on the slave side ");
        }
        if (number ==1){

            emperorsTurn();



        }





}

    public static void winOrLose(){
        int wincounter = 0;
        String win = "You won the round";
        String lose = "You lose the round ";

        if (wincounter >0) {
            System.out.println(win);
        }
        else if (wincounter == 0) {
            System.out.print(lose);
        }


    }

    public static void emperorsTurn() {
        Random cards = new Random();
        int computerinput = 0;
        for (int counter = 1; counter <= 3; counter++) {
            computerinput = 1 + cards.nextInt(2);
        }


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please pick the card you are playing. \n if you are playing the Emperor press 1, if you are playing the citizen press 2 ");
        int userinput = sc.nextInt();

        if (userinput == 1 && computerinput == 1) {
            System.out.println("you have played the emperor! \n the emperor is defeated by the slave");

        }
        else if (userinput ==1 && computerinput ==2) {
            System.out.println("you have played the emperor the emperor defeats the citizen");

            winOrLose();
            wincounter();
        }






        else if (userinput == 2) { //when the user input is 2
            if (computerinput == 1) {
                System.out.println("you have played the citizen, this defeats the slave");
                wincounter();
            } else if (computerinput == 2) {
                System.out.println("you have played the citizen, this ties with the citizen");
            }
            //print out something else if number is not 1,2 or 3
        }
    }

    public static void wincounter() {
        int i = 0;
        if (i < 1)i++;

        System.out.println("you have won " +i +" number of draws");
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a loop would be a simple solution.

Comment: so how where would i put that while loop?

Comment: @OwaisHassan Around the code that you want repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing a while loop that compares the number of cards left to the minimum number needed to play a game.

```
while (numberOfCards > minNumberNeeded) {
   playGame();
}
```

Comment: and would playGame(); be a method that executes the entire program? How would I go about writing that?

Comment: It would execute the game.
You need to figure out what logic to put into that function based on how the game is played.

Comment: do you think it would work if i put a new method around all of my code, except the main method, and used that?

Comment: You're not going to want to wrap your functions in another function, you take your functions and use them as components inside the playGame function.  ..It still looks like you have to write your actual game logic, such as who goes first, how a user turn works etc.